# Efficiency when overriding font for multiple views

Tags: android, performance, fonts

There are two ways to "globally" override the font used in android.

Creating a class that extends a view object and setting the type face, i.e.

```
public class TextViewRobotoRegular extends TextView {

    public TextViewRobotoRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            setTypeface(typeface);            
        }
    }
}
```

the other being defining a style and setting the typeface there

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

So my question is, which would be more memory-efficient?

Also, is there anyway to make a reference in the XML file to the `assets/fonts/<fontname>.ttf` file?  I'm trying to have all view objects have the same font, but I would like them all to reference one spot if I decide to change the font.

Comment: You are comparing two different things. Your Java code is loading a custom font; your style is simply choosing a particular standard font.

Comment: Is there a way to set a custom font within the xml file? So that the xml file could point to a specific font defined in the resources of the project? Perhaps something like `<resources>
    <typeFace name="roboto_regular">fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf</typeFace>
</resources>`

Comment: Alas, no. My point, though, is that you are asking about memory efficiency, and that would make more sense if you were comparing equivalent actions. The equivalent in your Java code would be to set the widget to `monospace`, not to load a `Typeface` from assets (let alone do so once per widget instance).

Comment: So I cannot do:
`<resources>
    <attr name="roboto_thin">fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf</attr>
</resources>`

and then reference this attribute as a fontfamily like:
    `<TextView
        android:fontFamily="@attr/roboto_thin"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="Example" />`

Comment: Correct, that is not supported.

Comment: So the only way of setting up a global reference to a custom font in a project is to create an extension of a view object and call the `setTypeFace` method, as shown in the code above?

Comment: There are other approaches (e.g., walking the widget hierarchy and calling `setTypeface()`) rather than creating custom classes. But you cannot set a custom typeface in a style or layout.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on caching the typeface?..or 'walking the widget hierarchy' if this leads to better performance?

Comment: If you use a search engine and look for how other people have addressed this issue, I feel fairly confident that you will come up with answers to those questions. If you still have concerns, ask fresh StackOverflow questions, as this is getting far too long for a comment chain, and this is not directly related to your specific question here.